# How to reset mongodb memory cache programmatically

Tags: c#, mongodb

Could you please tell me how to reset mongodb memory cache as is keeps on piling up.

The memory cache is removed when I restart the mongod.exe.

Can I do this programmatically using C# for Windows?

Comment: Historically, the Windows version of MongoDB has had memory issues which is why we ended up running on linux to avoid the Windows memory leak.  The official 10gen C# driver (or the underlying mongo excecutable) does not provide any functionality to remove the memory cache.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB doesn't control the way it uses memory, because it uses memory mapped files. It leaves the caching up to the operating system, so there's no way for it to tell the OS how to restrict or uncache what it has. See: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Caching

This is a good reason to make sure MongoDB is running on its own box. Otherwise, the free memory will be consumed, and other programs will struggle to get enough RAM from the OS.